# Output a single column from a datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

So this doesn't seem like it should be that difficult, but apparently I'm overlooking something..? I have a datatable that has 4 columns. I want to output **only** the second column from the datatable. Here's what I've got so far:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
** Datatable is set here **
Dim row As DataRow
Dim col As DataColumn

For Each row In dt.Rows
    'Output Column 2 here
    'This is what I had which obviously doesn't work
    Response.Write(row(col(1)))
    Response.Write("<br />")
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the line where you output the column value to this:

```
Response.Write(row(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

Dim col As DataColumn = dt.Columns(1)

Response.Write(row(col))

Looks like your issue is that the col variable wasn't set to anything